# Prevent numpy from vectorizing multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I created a set of little helper classes for working with degrees and radians. I have included some numpy ufuncs (radians, degrees, sin, cos...) so that I can have `deg` objects inside of numpy arrays, and perform numpy trig operations (e.g., `np.cos(np.array([5*deg, 10*deg, 15*deg]))`) on the numpy arrays.

However, I have discovered that when "multiplying" an `ndarray` by the `deg` class on the RHS, the numpy object's `__mul__` method gets invoked on the array, rather than `UnitMeta.__rmul__` leading to raising a `TypeError` inside of `NumberMixin.__new__` as desired. It works correctly (raises an error) when `deg` is the LHS, e.g. `deg * np.array([1])`.

Only a portion of the classes is shown below for brevity.

```
'deg.py'
from numbers import Number
import numpy as np

class UnitMeta(type):
    def __mul__(cls, other):
        return cls(other)
    def __rmul__(cls, other):
        '''So can write things like "1 * deg"'''
        return cls(other)

class NumberMixin():
    def __new__(cls, v):
        if not isinstance(v, Number):
            raise TypeError('A valid numeric type value is required. {} is not numeric.'.format(type(v)))
        return super().__new__()
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._v * other
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
    def radians(self): # NOTE: overridden in deg below 
        return np.radians(self._v)
    def degrees(self): # NOTE: overridden in deg below 
        return np.degrees(self._v)
    def sin(self):
        return np.sin(self._v)
    def cos(self):
        return np.cos(self._v)
    def tan(self):
        return np.tan(self._v)

class deg(NumberMixin, metaclass = UnitMeta):
    def __init__(self, d = 0.0):
        if isinstance(d, deg):
            self._v = d._v
            self._deg = d._deg
        else:
            self._v = np.radians(d)
            self._deg = d
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(type(other),UnitMeta):
            return NotImplemented
        else:
            return super().__mul__(other)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._deg) + '°'
    def __repr__(self):
        return str('deg({})'.format(self._deg))
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return self._deg.__format__(spec) + '°'
    def degrees(self):
        return self
    def radians(self):
        return self._v


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print('FAILURE: ', deg * np.array([1]) , ' exception not caught')
    except TypeError:
        print('SUCCESS: deg * np.array([1]) exception caught.')
    try:
        print('FAILURE: ', np.array([1]) * deg, ' exception not caught')
    except TypeError:
        print('SUCCESS: np.array([1]) * deg exception caught.')
```

Everything else works well.

I want to prevent numpy from doing this so that I can write things more like "normal math", e.g.:

```
5 * deg
```

...but have an exception come up, and not get swallowed, when something like this accidentally occurs:

```
a = np.array([5])
a * deg <- TypeError
```

Any suggestions? I haven't worked with numpy much as of yet, so apologies if there is an obvious solution.

Comment: First, that `deg` class sounds like it's going to kill performance. Second, if `a * deg` raises a `TypeError`, how else are you going to apply `deg` to every element of an array?

Comment: I fixed the above code- the problem is now showing up as written.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah you're probably right, but I don't care all that much about performance- I'm solving small problems. I don't want to apply deg to every element- it's a class. If I want an np.array of degs, I'll just do something like `np.array([n * deg for n in range(0,181)])`

Comment: If you don't care about performance, and you only want to deal with small problems, then why use `numpy`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To avoid putting for loops everywhere. However, you make a good point- I could just use the trig functions from `math`. That would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: However there's still the problem at hand, because a year from now who knows if I will remember that my deg class is swallowing numpy arrays.